# Customization of a live usb (persistent) to use Latex

Tags: usb, latex

I would like to prepare a live usb persistent to use Latex and be used as a initial instalation in another pc/usb if I need. I would like to know if I make the changes in this persistent version and use the same usb stick to install ubuntu, what I am going to find in the pc/usb stick installed: is it the original instalation (the one before the customization) or the one customized to run latex?

Answer (score 1):

Persistence will let you install Latex for that usb stick only. Installing Ubuntu from that stick to another PC will install the original Ubuntu only. You need to create a customized Ubuntu ISO image file containing all/any software that you want.

Install Ubuntu on a PC, then install all the software you want/need, then use Remastersys, UCK, PinguyBuilder, Cubic, Live-Magic or custom scripts to do it. Please mind that this process requires large amounts of time, memory and disk space (for temp files). Doing it directly from a usb stick may never work.